# wrapping Scaffold with Container for gradient background, How to set gradient to container background in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, containers, gradient

I'd like to wrap a `Scaffold` with a `Container` in order to get a gradient background that's also underneath the `AppBar`. Basically a full screen `gradient` background. However, my attempt doesn't do anything.
Is there another way of doing it, where I can keep the `AppBar` functionality but have it on top of a `gradient` that spans the whole screen?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Test',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.yellow,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Test'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          begin: Alignment.topRight,
          end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
          stops: [0.1, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9],
          colors: [
            Colors.yellow[800],
            Colors.yellow[700],
            Colors.yellow[600],
            Colors.yellow[400],
          ],
        ),
      ),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Icon(Icons.menu),
          backgroundColor: Color(0x00000000),
          elevation: 0.0,
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                'dummy text',
              ),
              Text(
                '5',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
              ),
              FloatingActionButton(
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                foregroundColor: Colors.black45,
                elevation: 0.0,
                onPressed: () {},
                tooltip: 'Play',
                child: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: add `scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.transparent` inside `ThemeData( ...`

Comment: thanks!
still in an early phase with flutter..

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In Your Code - Under `Scaffold` add - `backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,`

```
child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        appBar: AppBar(
        ..
```

Answer (score 103):

You can also add a gradient to the `AppBar` like this,

[image: awesome app bar preview]

```
new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Center(child: Text('Awesome AppBar')),
        flexibleSpace: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
                colors: [
                  const Color(0xFF3366FF),
                  const Color(0xFF00CCFF),
                ],
                begin: const FractionalOffset(0.0, 0.0),
                end: const FractionalOffset(1.0, 0.0),
                stops: [0.0, 1.0],
                tileMode: TileMode.clamp),
          ),
        ),
        child: ...,
      ),
      body: ...,
    );
```

LinearGradient parameters:

- `colors`: an array of the colors to be used in the gradient, in this case, two shades of blue.
- `begin`, `end`: position of the first color and the last color, in this case,
- `FractionalOffset` allows us to treat the coordinates as a range from 0 to 1 both for x and y. As we want an horizontal gradient, we use same Y for both measures, and the x changes from 0.0 (left) to 1.0 (right).
- `stops`: this array should have the same size than colors. It defines how the colors will distribute. [0.0, 1.0] will fill it from left to right. [0.0, 0.5] will fill the colors from left to half bar, etc.
- `tileMode`: what to do if the stops do not fill the whole area. In this case, we added clamp (it will reuse the last color used), but as our gradient goes from 0.0 to 1.0, it’s not really necessary.
- You can also add a child to the `Container`. e.g: some logo image

  ```
      child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Image.asset(
              "images/logo.png",
              width: 128,
              height: 128,
            )),
      ),
  ```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 20):

Simply add `FlexibleSpace` in `AppBar` and Decorate the container. Then the app bar is a gradient in the background.

```
appBar: AppBar(

      title: Text('Flutter Demo'),
      flexibleSpace: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
            end: Alignment.centerRight,
            colors: <Color>[
              Colors.red,
              Colors.blue
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 19):

I used this piece of code to set `background` color as a `gradient`

```
return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          body: Container(
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                gradient: new LinearGradient(
                  begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                  end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  colors: [
                    Color.fromARGB(255, 25,178,238),
                    Color.fromARGB(255, 21,236,229)
                  ],
                )),
            child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Image.asset(
                  "images/app_logo.png",
                  width: 128,
                  height: 128,
                )),
          ),
        ),
      );
```

Answer (score 3):

You simply use FlexibleSpace in the appbar

```
      appBar: AppBar(
      centerTitle: true,
      title: Text(widget.title),
      flexibleSpace: Container(
           decoration: BoxDecoration(
           gradient: LinearGradient(
           begin: Alignment.topLeft,
            end: Alignment.bottomRight,
            colors: <Color>[
              Colors.red,
              Colors.blue
            ])
           ),
          ),
         ),
```

Comment: Exact copy of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57089477/12483095)

Answer (score 2):

You can use directly below code for gradient color of any container or view

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Dashboard"),
      ),
      body: Container(
         alignment: Alignment.center,
         decoration: BoxDecoration(
         gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [Colors.red, Colors.blue, Colors.black])
         )
       ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set the color twice in the appBar and in the Container, just set the appBar like this and they will have the same color:

```
appBar: AppBar(
  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
  elevation: 0, //this will make the shadow of the appBar disappear and show the exact color of the background you setted.
  //and here put the rest of the configurations you need for the appBar.
)
```